# How to use faketime at bash?

Tags: bash, unix

Have a problem with command `faketime`.

Trying to use it, but always get an error:

```
faketime -t "2000-01-01 01:00:00"
/usr/bin/faketime: 102: exec: 2000-01-01 01:00:00: not found
```

I have Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you explain how to make it correct for date 2000-01-01 01:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Do you read `faketime` [man](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/faketime/) page?

```
faketime 'last Friday 5 pm' /bin/date
faketime '2000-01-01 01:00:00' /bin/date
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpfull first post. (Minor hint: I would use 4 blank intention for a code block to simulate prompts as > at the beginning of the line is a quote).